# ec2 can't access another s3 file in the same bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket and an EC2 with a role that access to that bucket. The ec2 can access `s3://mybucket/folderA/file1`, but can't access `s3://mybucket/folderB/file2`. I can't seem to figure out why I can access file1 but not file2 from the ec2 instance. When I try to download file2 like this:

`aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/folderB/file2 /home/ec2-user/file2`

I get this error:

`fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`

But I don't get that error when i download file1:

`aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/folderA/file1 /home/ec2-user/file1`

----EDIT------

I missed the 403 error...so I guess the question is why isn't it seeing the file

----EDIT-----

here is my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "1-1-1",
    "Id": "Policy111111111",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Sxxxxxxx1234",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-a8xxxxx"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "RequiredEncryptedPutObject",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                        "AES256",
                        "aws:kms"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: May be totally unrelated, but are you aware that s3 returns 403 when there is no such file (instead of 404)?

Comment: nope...I completely missed that...the file is there though..so I guess the question is why isn't it seeing the file?

Comment: @user3707125 Not quite. It returns 403 if the object does not exist *and* you do not have list permission. It returns 404 if the object does not exist but you do have list permission.

Comment: so its not seeing the object and I don't have permissions for `folderB` then?

Comment: Either the object exists and you do not have permission to get it. Or the object does not exist and you do not have permission to list it.

Comment: @user2061886, I implied that you may have misspelled the filename, but because of the error code you may think that the issue is the policy. jarmod described the possible reasons pretty clear in his last comment.

Comment: yep...the does exists...

Comment: @user2061886, can you post the bucket policy (without private info)?

Comment: made an edit with it..

Comment: @user2061886,  change `"Action": "s3:GetObject"` to `"Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket"]` and re-check whether you still receive 403, if it changes to 404 - then the problem is the file, otherwise - policy.

Comment: I still get a 403 error...

Comment: Can you try changing black-list policy to white-list? I.e. change `"Effect": "Deny"` to `"Effect": "Allow"` and `"StringNotEquals"` to `"StringEquals"`?

Comment: do you have any policy attached to the EC2 instance role?

Comment: Your `Version` is invalid. It should be set to `"Version": "2012-10-17"`. I assume you simply changed the value when pasting it into your question but wanted to point it out in case that's the actual value you have in your policy.

Comment: Your Bucket Policy contains only `Deny` statements. You must have another policy that is granting you permissions to access S3 otherwise you wouldn't be able to access `folderB/file2`. Please have a look at the permissions assigned to your IAM User.

Comment: It could be *object-level* permissions that make the difference, here.